# What is the purpose of leading underscores in variable names in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in Kotlin and confused in underscore in a variable as **_view**.
Please help me.

```
class MainActivityPresenter(_view: View): Presenter {
    
        private var view: View = _view
```

Comment: The suggested dup does not seem to cover this case (i.e. having an identifier with a leading underscore but also additional characters).

Comment: From my understanding, this is usually done when you have two properties with the same name, with one of them being private and the other being public and relying one the private one.

Comment: I believe they don't have any specific meaning  in Kotlin. This is just how someone named the variable, probably to avoid duplicating the name (but he/she didn't really have to do this).

Comment: This particular case doesn't provide any benefits over `class MainActivityPresenter(private var view: View): Presenter` and _may_ be due to the author following some bad guidance or misunderstanding a more useful case like the one in Skizo-ozᴉʞS's answer.

Comment: @Hubby is not clear at all my question? You marked as a correct then you removed is missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can read about [`Names for backing properties`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#names-for-backing-properties) and you'll understand it better.

> If a class has two properties which are conceptually the same but one is part of a public API and another is an implementation detail, use an underscore as the prefix for the name of the private property

This is common in `viewModel` where you have your private val of a `MutableLiveData` and then you have the same name variable without the underscore that is the one is accessible from outside but not mutable.

Example :

```
private val _user: MutableLiveData<User>
val user: LiveData<User>
    get() = _user
```

In your case would be to don't confuse the `View` that is in your `Presenter` and the `View` that is by constructor.

Comment: In above case `_view` is not a property. It is only the variable of the constructor and it is used to set `view` property - they are the same.

Comment: Yep, but the thing is that I don't know if they have this code because they are changing just the `view` property, I need more code to try to give a reason why they chose this way of naming variables.